# Web.xml file not working properly

Tags: java, xml, apache, tomcat, web-applications

I'm trying to upload my website on an apache server with TomCat and can't seem to get it to work. When I upload my .war file on my VPS the site loads but when I try log in for example (which uses UserActionServlet) it then crashes the site and goes to a 503 page.

I've tried loads of different ways of doing it including this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>UserActionServlet</servlet-name>
<displayable-name xml:lang="en">My Servlet</displayable-name>
<description>The Servlet</description>
<servlet-class>Servlet.UserActionServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<!-- The mapping for the JSP servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>



</session-config>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error-404.jsp</location>
</error-page>  

</web-app>
```

Here are some pictures which may help a bit to see where the files are located.

**Picture 1**
[image: Servlet picture]

**Picture 2**
[image: Web.xml picture]

Anyone have any idea of where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Does it work on local host ?

Comment: Yes it works fine on local host but not on the VPS. I should've mentioned that, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `<servlet-name>` within the `<servlet>` element and the value of `<servlet-name>` withing the `<servlet-mapping>` element should correspond.

i.e. change `jsp` to `UserActionServlet`

Comment: `<!-- The mapping for the JSP servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UserActionServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>` So that's it? Will try now.

Comment: Tried that and now my site won't load at all, it now says: The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: try this: `<url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>` and then visit `${host}:${port}/${app_context}/foo`

Comment: Tried that and same problem as before, site loads fine but when I try log in I get a 503 page and then the server needs to be rebooted for the site to load again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps should zoom down the problem step-by-step:

1. Are you able to serve a HTML page just from Apache Web Server?
2. Are you able to serve a HTML page just from the deployed war file commenting out the problematic servlet?